# How to reflect update in database server to website and android app(instantly)?

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee, synchronization, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on a project with website and android app. I want when in a session if user updates the database from website it should reflect in the app (instantly) and vice -versa.
I have read about sync and cloud messaging . What could be the best approach for this problem.
I am using J2ee for website and a JBoss server .Please help?

Answer (score 1):

If it needs to be (nearly) instant, your best bets are either using GCM [http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html] or keeping a socket/connection open from your app to the website that will keep them in sync. However, in my experience, what I have done in the past and worked very well for me was to have a hook in the app so that whenever you are going to access the view that you want to see updated it goes to the server and then updates itself. I am unsure if you need this to be available when offline too, in which case you will have no choice but to keep syncing with the server at regular intervals.

Comment: How many users will your app have? As leaving a socket open might not be a good idea if too many users

Comment: This would be session based so at a point there would be only one user